# How to delete li element in ajax response function

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

I am trying to delete the `li` element which is the parent of the clicked `a` element.

This is my code:

```
function vanish(id_arg){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/vanish/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id_to_delete: id_arg},
        }).success(function(data){
           document.getElementsByTagName('li').getElementById(id_arg).remove();
        });
    }
```

and this is my html:

```
{% for i in p %}
<li id="{{i.id}}"> <a>{{i.name}}</a><a onclick="vanish({{i.id}})" class="item">delete</a></li>    
{% endfor %}
```

p is the query response containing name and id.

`vanish()` will delete the item from database and as a ajax response I want to delete the item from page also. I need delete and not hide.

My problem is that it is not deleting from the page, I am trying to catch the `li` with javascript and `remove()` it but never find the right code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will select all links and remove the parent element above it.  If you have other links on the page I would recommend maybe giving the link a class so you could specify which ones you are going to remove.  Also note that calling remove() on the li will delete everything inside the element as well.

```
$('#' + id_arg).click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Edit:
Read the question to fast, you can include this in your success function on your ajax call:

```
$('#' + id_arg).closest('li').remove();
```

Comment: as ajax response, can i use this function ?

Comment: updated my answer, you can use the second code snippet in your ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Just locate the child first and delete from the document body.

```
          var child = document.getElementById(id_arg);
          document.body.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: but it is saying ``TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName("li").getElementById is not a function``  , some typo here ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There is no need of the `getElementsByTagName`. You can locate your child directly by `id`. Updated the answer.

Comment: ``NotFoundError: Node was not found`` it says now. the element exists. :(

Comment: Make sure, you are using the right `id` of the element. Alert `id_arg` and verify.