# Remove script after clicking in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want do remove the div with id="fbb" after i click on it. Please help

Here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide() {
    document.getElementById('fbb').style.display = 'none';
}
<script>
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:60px;opacity:1.1;z-index:9999;" id="fbb" onclick="hide()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "";
    google_ad_slot = "";
    google_ad_width = ;
    google_ad_height = ;
</script>
<!-- casorla-bet_main_Blog1_300x250_as -->
<script type="text/javascript" target="_blank" class="test" src="#">
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: If you google for your issue you will find lots of answers

Comment: remove is different from hide.. what you're doing is just hidding it.. I would recommend doing in jquery something like this `$('#fbb').remove()`

Comment: This question has the jQuery tag but has nothing to do with it. If you're using jQuery you don't need to make a hide() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete li element in ajax response function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870479/how-to-delete-li-element-in-ajax-response-function)

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp It covers creating and removing elements..good luck

Comment: check this answer you will find exactly what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript

Comment: you can just pass the object of the div in your method and use`.remove`. try this https://jsfiddle.net/eqgj2s1n/

Comment: What's the point of removing a script? The script already ran when the page was loaded, removing it won't have any effect on the code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code line:

```
document.getElementById('fbb').style.display = 'none';
```

with either javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("fbb");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Or as posted above, with jQuery:

```
$('#fbb').remove()
```

Comment: Oh, that is confusing I meant replace your code (that first line), with either pure javascript (the second line), or jquery (the third line). Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this, with jQuery:

```
$( "#fbb" ).remove();
```

Or, with vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("fbb").remove();
```

The JavaScript example might not work with older browsers (which basically means older IE).

Comment: `#` is an invalid character in `getElementById("#fbb")`. Should be: `getElementById("fbb")`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use and **".hide()"** method with Jquery. Then add **".show()"**, if its temporarily.

```
$('#fbb').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
```